# Why object is being deinitialized when ActiveReferenceCount > 0

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I'm reading about `ARC` and being confused about increasing `Reference Count`. My example code is below.
My first class:

```
class Owner{
var name: String
weak var cat:Cat? //Cat reference count will not increase because of 'weak'
init(name: String){
    self.name = name
    print("Owner class is initialized.")
  }

deinit{
    print("Owner class is deinitialized.")
  }  
}
```

My Second Class:

```
class Cat{
var name: String
var owner: Owner?

init(name: String){
    self.name = name
    print("Cat class is initialized.")
  }

deinit {
    print("Cat class is deinitilized.")
  }
}
```

My Class usage code:

```
var mamun: Owner? = Owner(name: "Mamun") //OwnerAR = 1
var vutu: Cat? = Cat(name: "Vutu") // CatAR = 1
mamun?.cat = vutu // CatAr = 1
vutu?.owner = mamun // OwnerAR = 2
mamun = nil // OwnerAR = 1
vutu = nil // CatAR = 0
```

Output:

> Owner class is initialized.
>   Cat class is initialized.
>   Cat class is deinitilized.
>   Owner class is deinitialized.

Confution: When `Owner` reference count is 1, why it is being deinitialized after `vutu = nil` code execution. Am i doing wrong on counting reference?

Comment: FYI - it is more common in a parent/child relationship for the parent to have a strong reference to its children and for a child to have a weak reference to its parent. This doesn't affect the issue in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `vutu` to `nil`, that object's reference count goes to zero and it gets deinitialized as expected. In the process of getting deinitialized, it releases any strong references to objects it has. So its `owner` is released. That brings the reference count to 0 for the object referenced by your `mamun` variable. And that is why you see the last message of `Owner class is deinitialized.`.

Comment: It does happened when cat `var` is weak, but when `cat` var is strong `deinit` is not calling

Comment: if both `cat` and `owner` are strong then you get a circular  reference cycle. That's bad. One and only one of `cat` or `owner` must be `weak`.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand. Whenever a class is `deinitialized` all of its properties reference count are being reduced by 1.

Comment: Close. Any strong references to class instances are released.

Answer (score 1):

mamun?.cat = vutu // `CatAr = 1 (1 by vutu)`

vutu?.owner = mamun // `OwnerAR = 2 (1 by vutu's owner and another by mamun)`

mamun = nil // `OwnerAR = 1 (1 by vutu's owner) == cannot deinit until vutu deinit`

vutu = nil // `CatAR = 0 == vutu deinit == OwnerAR = 0 == mamun deinit`